# In a numpy array is dtype np.datetime64 or pandas object datetime.date faster?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to filter through a date array the fastest possible? Should I use pandas or numpy? If I use numpy what data type should I use?

I have a large dataframe where I need to loop through a range and pull the data from a date range. It's taking longer than I need since I'm also testing the data and re-running it is getting quite tedious.

***NOTE:** After looking for questions that answer this, I wasn't able to find a suitable answer so I posted this in case anyone else is in a similar situation. The answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing three options, using numpy with pandas objects is the fastest. This is quite significant when the dataset gets larger and when you test the "output" separately from creating the numpy array.

*Pandas dataframe only

```
%%timeit
start_date = date(2015, 1, 26)
end_date = date(2018, 1, 26)

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date), columns=['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df['Range'] = range(df.shape[0])

max_date = date(2017, 1, 1)
df.loc[df['Date'] <= max_date]
3.02 ms ± 126 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*Numpy only

```
%%timeit
start_date = date(2015, 1, 26)
end_date = date(2018, 1, 26)

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date), columns=['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df['Range'] = range(df.shape[0])

max_date = date(2017, 1, 1)
np_df = np.array(df.values, dtype=np.datetime64)
output = np.where(np_df[:,0] <= max_date)
3.99 ms ± 144 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Numpy with pandas objects

```
%%timeit
start_date = date(2015, 1, 26)
end_date = date(2018, 1, 26)

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date), columns=['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df['Range'] = range(df.shape[0])

max_date = date(2017, 1, 1)
np_df = np.array(df.values)
output = np.where(np_df[:,0] <= max_date)
2.44 ms ± 31.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```